# OOM when compressing images?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, image-compression

I'm getting OOM when compressing image by using following code.i have recycled the bitmap after writing to file.but when compressing large images or continuously repeating three or four times the app crashes with OOM error.can any one help me out to get rid from this ?

```
/**
 * A simple class that compresses images from resources given
 */
public class ImageCompressor {

    public static String compressImage(final Context context, final String filePath) {

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
        // you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

        // max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        // width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        // setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

        // inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        // this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
        }
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            // load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        // check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out;
        String filename = getFilename(context);
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            // write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
            if (bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
                bmp.recycle();
            if (scaledBitmap != null && !scaledBitmap.isRecycled())
                scaledBitmap.recycle();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;
    }

    private static String getFilename(final Context context) {
        return (Util.getCompressedPicPath(context).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    }

    /**
     * Calculate an inSampleSize for use in a {@link BitmapFactory.Options} object when decoding
     * bitmaps using the decode* methods from {@link BitmapFactory}. This implementation calculates
     * the closest inSampleSize that is a power of 2 and will result in the final decoded bitmap
     * having a width and height equal to or larger than the requested width and height.
     *
     * @param options   An options object with out* params already populated (run through a decode*
     *                  method with inJustDecodeBounds==true
     * @param reqWidth  The requested width of the resulting bitmap
     * @param reqHeight The requested height of the resulting bitmap
     * @return The value to be used for inSampleSize
     */
    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }


}
```

*And the requirement of this pease of code is i have to compress the image before uploading to server.*

Comment: use some image loading libraries like picasso or glide

Comment: Actually i have to compress the image before uploading to server.so the solution given by you isn't good enough.